# How do you exclude language from SXA sitemap?

Tags: sxa

Sitecore 8.2.7
SXA 1.7

Our website does not render the language in the urls, however the sitemap does. Is there a way to ensure that SXA generates the urls like it does for the navigation?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<urlset xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.company.com/en</loc>
    <lastmod>2018-06-06</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.company.com/en" />
  </url>
</urlset>
```

### Update

Sitecore support acknowledged this as a bug. May be slated for SXA 1.8.

Comment: as far I remember this is a known bug. which sxa version do you have.

Comment: Still an issue in SXA 1.8

Comment: Actually scratch that it's not an issue in 1.8 - the <loc> is correct, it just also adds the alternate hreflang even if you only have one language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, it appears that the `SitemapHandler` doesn't always obey the `langaugeEmbedding` option set in in the configuration. I think the problem is in the `ResolveLanguageEmbedding` function in the `LocalizableLinkProvider`.

#### Replace the SitemapHandler

To fix this, I simply overrode the SXA `SitemapHandler` and overrode this method:

```
protected virtual UrlOptions GetUrlOptions()
{
    UrlOptions defaultUrlOptions = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
    SiteContext site = Context.Site;
    defaultUrlOptions.Site = site;
    int num1 = 0;
    defaultUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = num1 != 0;
    int num2 = 1;
    defaultUrlOptions.SiteResolving = num2 != 0;
    return defaultUrlOptions;
}
```

So that it would either be hard coded to set the required languageEmbedding or you can manually read the link provider settings and make sure it is set correctly.

To override the `SitemapHandler`, replace this processor with your patch:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.SitemapHandler, Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.config">
    <CacheExpiration>30</CacheExpiration>
</processor>
```

#### Replace the LinkProvider

We also had to replace the SXA `LocalizableLinkProvider` and override the `GetItemUrl` method:

```
public override string GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
{
    if (options.LanguageEmbedding == LanguageEmbedding.AsNeeded)
    {
        options.LanguageEmbedding = this.LanguageEmbedding;
    }

    return base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
}
```

We did this because the `LanguageEmbedding` value in the options passed in had different values to the settings in the configuration which caused the language to be embedded for some SXA controls and not others. This sanitized that.